# How to add a value to existing value using sql query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

How to update field to add value to existing value?
For example I have the below product table.

```
            product   quantity
              x         4
              y         5
              z         3
```

Is there a way to simply add value to the quantity?
like

```
int qn = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update product set group1 = group1 + qn where productname = '@productname'", con);
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productname", TextBox1.Text));
```

I want to add textbox value to 4 so that the credit to be updated where product='x'
i am getting error "Invalid column name 'qn'"(group1 = group1 + qn). Please suggest me solve this error??

Comment: Your table doesnt have group1 column

Comment: I mentioned quantity as group1 in update query

Comment: @Meena Why? Why don't you use it your _real_ column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `qn` as another parameter and passed along with the query, so your query will be like the following:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update product set group1 = group1 + @qn where productname = @productname", con);
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qn", qn));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productname", TextBox1.Text));
```

Comment: group1 is not the column name. Its quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes around your parameter in SQL string.

```
"update product set group1 = group1 + qn where productname = '@productname'"
                                                           //^^           ^^
```

You don't need single quotes when using parameters.

**Also** add parameters for `qn` as well. 
like:

```
int qn = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update product set group1 = group1 + @qn where productname = @productname", con);
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productname", TextBox1.Text));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qn", qn));
```

It is better if you enclose your command and connection object in `using` statement , that will ensure proper disposal of resources.

Comment: My code is working fine, hereafter i will add 'using' statement. Thanks for your suggestion,...